# How to replace the get() function with computeIfAbsent() in a Map?

Tags: java, hashmap, sonarcloud

as a result of a Sonarcloud analysis, it was suggested that I should use the computeIfAbsent() method instead of get() on listeners which is defined as Map<String, List>. Since I am unfamiliar with this method, would anyone know how to properly refactor the method indicated by the following java code in order to properly use computeIfAbsent() instead of get()?

```
public void addListener(String event, EventListener listener) {
    List<EventListener> eventListeners = listeners.get(event);
    if (eventListeners == null) {
        eventListeners = new ArrayList<>();
        listeners.put(event, eventListeners);
    }
    eventListeners.add(listener);
}
```

Comment: "Since I am unfamiliar with this method" - did you read the doc?

Comment: @Eugene Yes but I failed to adapt the examples to my given context.

Comment: show what you did then, and what specific problem you faced

Comment: `listeners.computeIfAbsent(event, ignoreMe -> new ArrayList<>()).add(event);`

Comment: the thing i didn't understand is if i have to replace the whole body of the method with what you wrote or just replace the get() method. i was able to obtain List<EventListener> eventListeners = listeners.computeIfAbsent(event, k-> new ArrayList<>());

Comment: you did 99% of the work then :) and yes you can replace the entire body

Comment: By the way event is an EventListener so I cannot use it in the add(). can I replace the whole body with your code or I need to declare the list as showed in my example? EDIT: I think that the correct way is: listeners.computeIfAbsent(event, k-> new ArrayList<>()).add(listener);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are after?

```
listeners.computeIfAbsent(event, ignoreMe -> new ArrayList<>()).add(listener);
```